# How do I solve this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Define ${[X_n]}$ by: $X_n = 3, X_{n+1} = {\frac 12} (X_{n-1} + {2\over X_{n-1}})$

- a) Show that for any n≥1 we have $X_n$≥ $\sqrt{2}$
- b) Show that {$X_n$} is decreasing.
- c) Deduce from (a) and (b) that {$X_n$} is convergent and
  find its limits.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. It helps to know what you have tried so we don't give answers that are too obvious or too above your level. To show that it is decreasing try showing $X_{n+1}/X_n \leq 1$. To find its limits note that you will have $X_{n+1} "=" X_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so try solving the quadratic equation $a = (a + 2/a)/2.$

Comment: You're definition of the sequence doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually completely lost on this so anything is helpful! I was actually using this thread as a reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306976/prove-the-sequence-x-n-fracx-n-12-fraca2x-n-1-rightarrow-sqrt

I'm not too experienced with series so I think the main issue im running into is finding the limit.

Comment: Lol @David H , I'll mention that to my professor :)

Comment: @user116941 If he wrote the problem, then you should definitely mention it. But most likely you just didn't transcribe the problem correctly. Look at how do you defined the sequence. Does it make sense to you? You wrote $X_n=3$. How can you have a decreasing sequence of 3's?

Comment: @DavidH The series is defined by both of those. The only difference between this and the page is copied it from is that the square brackets in the first line should be curved.

Comment: @user116941 OK then, if you think you have defined a sequence then can you tell me what the first term of the sequence is? What about the next?

Comment: If you truly have $X_{n+1}=\frac 12(X_{n-1}+\frac2{X_{n-1}})$, then you have two parallel, independent sequences which must have separate initial values...

Comment: @abiessu If that were the case though, I don't think a decreasing descreasing sequence would be possible.

Comment: @DavidH I mentioned earlier that I don't have much experience with series. However, by looking at part (a) I believe that that argument doesn't hold simply because part (a) asked to prove $X_n≥ 2$ which would be impossible to do if what you say is true. 

My first instinct is to use tranduction. However, I am not sure how to as $x_{n+1}$ is a function of $x_{n−1}$ . I think I'll proceed with my instinct and keep you guys updated with my results :) All helpful ideas are welome

Comment: @davidh: I think maybe setting $X_1=3,X_2=2$ would work...  Setting aside the obvious problems like "$X_n=1$", etc.

Answer (score 1):

To find the limit, solve $X = \frac12(X + \frac2X).$ To see that it is decreasing, write the solution as $X_n = X + \epsilon_n,$ and see how $\epsilon_n$ behaves.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but can I do that since the second part of the sequence says that $x_{n+1}$ is a function of $x_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: @user116941 That is obviously a typo. $X_n$ is a function of $X_{n-1}.$